# compute derivative of first order function

Tags: matlab, derivative

I have a problem when computing the derivative of a first order function as below:

```
syms x(t)
xd = diff(x);
y = xd*xd;
```

how to compute derivative of y by xd;

```
functionalDerivative(y,xd);
```

Then, it raises an error as below:

```
Error using symengine
The variable 'diff(x(t), t)' is invalid.
```

The result should be:

```
2*diff(x,t)
```

I also think about name xd as a symbolic variable, then use diff(y,xd) but this way is not good for some situation. Do we have any method can directly compute the derivative of a differential function?
Please suggest me some solutions.
Thank in advance!

Comment: I can't replicate this in R2016b. Are those three lines really your only code? What `version` of Matlab are you using?

Comment: Yes, It is my actual code, I am using 2016a. Which is the code line you can not run?

Comment: I see what's happening. It's the `functionalDerivative(y,xd);` line that throws the error, not your first three lines. @TroyHaskin's approach is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I find it a little odd that the Symbolic Engine can't handle that, lacking a better word I'll borrow one from the TeX world, unexpandable expression.  However, you can get around the limitation by [`subs`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html)-ing in a temporary variable, taking the derivative, and `subs`-ing it back in:

```
>> syms u(t)
>> dydxd = subs(functionalDerivative(subs(y,xd(t),u(t)),u),u(t),xd(t))
dydxd(t) =
2*diff(x(t), t)
```

Hopefully this `subs` approach will work in most cases, but more complex expressions for `y` may make it not work.

Comment: It's not made explicit in the documentation for [`functionalDerivative`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/functionalderivative.html), but the function seems to require that the second argument be an "abstract"  or ["arbitrary" symbolic function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/create-symbolic-functions.html), i.e., a function without a definition.